# Populate select dropdown with jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Is it possible to populate a select dropdown with a jstree structure like in case of [jquery easy ui](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=).

Generating jstree in a div is possible but cannot do the same for a select dropdown. How could it be achieved?

```js
 $('#data').jstree({
  'core' : {
   'data' : [
    { "text" : "Root node", "children" : [
      { "text" : "Child node 1" },
      { "text" : "Child node 2" }
    ]}
   ]
  }
 });
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Hope this helps. Instead of creating a select with a tree inside, you can make it look like the same. You can create an empty input, when clicked will show the jstree. and when the node is selected, hide the tree and display node's text in the input.